# laravel file_get_contents of a route get no response

Tags: php, laravel, file-get-contents

I have a route:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'playlist'), function()
{
   Route::get('raw/{id}', array('as'=>'rawPlaylist', 'uses'=>'PlaylistsController@raw'));
});
```

When I open the URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/playlist/raw/1
```

Everything is fine and the page will load and show me the view.

In a controller I get the URL:

```
$url = URL::route('rawPlaylist', 1);
```

**The problem:**
I want read the view and store the whole view into a variable:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
```

echo $url is http://localhost:8000/playlist/raw/1 this is right.

But this does not work. I get no response, and the php artisan serve breaks.
Why? What is wrong here?

Comment: please see url echo $url; ?

Comment: echo $url is `http://localhost:8000/playlist/raw/1` this is right.

Comment: No right: see your url http://localhost:8000/de/playlist/raw/1

Comment: continuously invoke the same url. file_get_contents($url) content persistents connect your server.

Comment: yes you are right. I change my route now to http://localhost:8000/playlist/raw/1 .. instead the /de/ . It is now the same URL but it did not work too...

Comment: You shouldn't be make HTTP-requests internally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not able to use `file_get_contents` on a laravel route because the laravel routes aren't actual paths to the view file.

You can tell because the your view isn't stored in the folder `de/playlist/raw`, it's stored in `app/views/pathtoyourrawview`.

I haven't tried it, but I'm assuming you can capture your view's code into a variable by using:

```
$html = View::make('rawPlaylist')->render();
```

Basically, instead of returning your `View::make` result you write it to a variable.

Comment: `$html = View::make('rawPlaylist')->render();` to ensure that the actual HTML is returned instead of a view object ;)

Comment: No problem. Glad we could help!