# Get HTML content from URL (of own site)

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, file-get-contents

I am trying to get the HTML of a URL on my own site.
The site is built with laravel 5.4.

I am trying to get the HTML content of an endpoint so i can store it in the database as plain text.

but for some reason i keep getting continuous loading, even though i'm running on localhost.

this is what i've tried according to some questions ([Can't seem to get a web page's contents via cURL - user agent and HTTP headers both set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675611/cant-seem-to-get-a-web-pages-contents-via-curl-user-agent-and-http-headers-b)) i've seen here on stack overflow:

```
$url = url("template/1/11"); // http://localhost:8000/template/1/11
$html = file_get_contents($url);
```

AND

```
$url = url("template/1/11"); // http://localhost:8000/template/1/11  
$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt(... other options you want...)

$html = curl_exec($c);

if (curl_error($c))
    die(curl_error($c));

// Get the status code
$status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($c);
```

Is there a reason i'm getting this behavior? 
Please help i just need the HTML content of the URL

Comment: What's in the PHP error log?

Comment: @mkaatman php doesn't log any error about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the file's extension in your URL.

If your file is named `index.html` and is inside a folder called `template`, it's incorrect to use url as `template/index`, rather, you have to change it to `template/index.html`.

**EDIT:**

I had misread a part of the question. Apparently `file_get_contents()` doesn't work on Laravel routes, I suggest you to  refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27945755/8104581).

From the link:

```
$html = View::make($url)->render();
```

You might have to adjust the url if it's not pointing to the right route.

Comment: none of my URLs end with `.php` or `.html`. i am not pointing to a file but a PHP laravel route that when visited on the browser, shows a HTML page

Comment: @RaymondAtivie Updated my answer.

Comment: This worked for me as expected. and like suggested, i had to tweak my `$url` to point to the view and pass my data with it `$html = View::make("template.page", $data)->render()`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a laravel route which is fine, but the way you're doing it PHP will interpret as a local filename and the route won't be processed. You need to use the fully qualified domain name and path for the URL.

Comment: That is the full domain name path. the $url equals `"// http://localhost:8000/template/1/11"` i updated the question to reflect that

Comment: You need to literally set that as your URL: `$url = url("http://localhost:8000/template/1/11");`

Comment: If you look in your php error log it's going to tell you that path doesn't exist because it is looking for public/template/1/11 which is not a file. It's a laravel route so you need to run it with the FQDN and port in front.